# Can I add menu on other android application?

Tags: android

I want to add menu on other android application . For example , the user snaps photo with android phone. When user select option menu to save, I want to add this opiton menu on my project menu .Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot alter/add the behavior of other android application unless you go ahead and customize the ROM.

What you can do though for your case is to create an application that allows user to capture picture using Android camera Intent. Once the image returns to your application you can show your options menu. The other approach would be to create a custom Camera application.